# foreach over multiple lists at once

Tags: syntax

Are there any languages that support foreach over multiple lists at once?  Something like this:

```
 foreach (string a in names, string b in places, string c in colors) {
      // do stuff with a, b, c
 }
```

Sure, this can be done with a regular for loop:

```
 for (int n = 0; n<max, n++) {
      a = names[n]; b = places[n]; c = colors[n];
 }
```

but this loses the abstraction of foreach.

My meager google-fu only reveals people asking how to do multi-foreach in various languages that don't support it.  I'm guessing that *some* language uses it, I just can't figure out which one.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this question?

Comment: A project I'm on needs a syntax for something like multi-foreach.  If there's a syntax already out there, I'd like to use that instead of inventing a new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, Python can do that:

```
for a, b, c in zip(names, places, colors):
    pass
```

`zip` builds a list of tuples from the iterables passed to it. Python's `for` loop supports "unpacking", that is to say the tuples are split into their components. It's a weak form of pattern matching.

Comment: Note that this particular feature (iterating over several things "in parallel") arises naturally from a simpler and more general-purpose features (tuple unpacking). There's no special syntax for this in particular (as OP seems to be expecting), and that's a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

- In C#, you can transform multiple collections into one collection of tuples, then use a `foreach`. There is no specific language syntax, but .NET Framework still allows you to do it.
- In SQL, you can use `join`. I'm not sure if the "languages" you're looking for extend to SQL.

Note that in all cases, there is an ambiguity with your simple. What if `colors.length < places.length`? If `places.length > names.length`, would the remaining places be simply discarded?

---

Example for C#:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var names = new[] { "John", "Bill", "Joel" };
    var places = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    var colors = new[] { Color.AliceBlue, Color.BlueViolet, Color.DarkMagenta };

    var zip = names.Zip(places, (n, p) => new { n, p }).Zip(colors, (t, c) => new { Name = t.n, Place = t.p, Color = c });

    foreach (var z in zip)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", new[] { (object)z.Name, z.Place, z.Color }));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Or, using an extension method:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> ZipSeveral<T1, T2, T3>(this IEnumerable<T1> first, IEnumerable<T2> second, IEnumerable<T3> third)
{
    return first.Zip(second, (a, b) => new { a, b }).Zip(third, (t, c) => Tuple.Create(t.a, t.b, c));
}
```

you can reduce the code to a simple `foreach`:

```cs
foreach (var z in names.ZipSeveral(places, colors))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", new[] { (object)z.Item1, z.Item2, z.Item3 }));
}
```